# Alfresco 4.2c CIFS configuration issue

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, alfresco-share, cifs

I got a fresh installation of Alfresco 4.2 on Ubuntu 12.04. I had "successfully" configured CIFS and modified iptables to include (NAT) ports(1445 TCP -- 445 TCP and 1137-1139 TCP/UDP to 137-139 TCP/UDP) for SMB and NetBios. Also the machine is an EC2 instance at amazon so i've created the Security group to include inbound traffic 445,137-139 TCP and 137-139 UDP.  When connecting from a windows machine using network drive, I successfully connect (seems port 445 is working) but just show two folders  (one is site-name and the other swsdp). When i moved to the site folder there is no content (\server\alfresco\site-name), so is missing the documentLibrary and all subfolders.
 I've double checked that the User used to connect had permissions to see the content (even connect as Administrator and still the problem). Also i have set debug for CIFS under Alfresco's log4j with non-error or anything under the application log.

I followed steps advised on  http://andoylang.wordpress.com/2010/07/20/alfresco-with-cifs/  and try to isolate the problem within the linux box. When i used sbmclient to connect i got the following error:

```
bitnami@ip-10-46-57-42:/opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/shared/classes$ smbclient -U user \\\\localhost\\drive -p 1139  
Enter user's password:xxxxx
read_fd_with_timeout failed, read error = NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT.
Receiving SMB: Server 127.0.0.1 stopped responding
session request to LOCALHOST failed (Call timed out: server did not respond after 20000 milliseconds)
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Java] Server=[Alfresco CIFS Server 6.0.0]
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME`
```

So is my undestanding that the aunthentication service failed. I got the following debug entries at  /opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties:

```
# CIFS server debugging

log4j.logger.org.alfresco.smb.protocol=debug

log4j.logger.org.alfresco.smb.protocol.auth=debug
```

But there not output associated to this Auth error on the log file. Is this the correct log4j file to enable this debug?
What else i can do for troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was also answered in [BitNami Community Forum](http://answers.bitnami.com/questions/12699/cifs-on-bitnami-alfresco-42c-amazon-ec2-ami-ami-bitnami-alfresco-42c-1-linux-ubuntu-12041-x86_64-ebs/12770). The issue was related to the smbclient command, not Alfresco itself, that is why you didn't find anything related in the Alfresco log files. The following smbclient command should be used:

```
$ smbclient  \\\\127.0.0.1\\Alfresco -U user -p 1139
Enter user's password: 
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Java] Server=[Alfresco CIFS Server 6.0.0]
smb: \\>
```